# Using input of a 1-12 (period-based) slicer in a measure

Tags: powerbi

I would like to use a slicer based on the 12-months of a year to calculate the yearly budget up until a specific month and be able to compare it to realised costs.
Slicer:

[image: slicer]

So, if I am in month 8 (August), the realized costs are shown up until then. Now I also want to be able to create a measure based on that slicer input (8). The measure would then calculate the following: 8/12*the budget. I only need the integer 8 to be able to make the calculation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI has great time intelligence functions. Google "Power BI date table" to learn more. There's a ton out there. Learning to use a date table is essential in Power BI.

The typical pattern is to create a [date table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/model-date-tables) that has the full date as the key, and columns for your slicers. In your case, you would have the Month (or often Month-Year) on the slicer, which should come from a column on the date table. Then you have a relationship between the date table and your data.

In your report, you should have DAX Measures like this:

```
Cost = SUM('Data table'[Cost])
Cost YTD = TOTALYTD( [Cost], DimDate[Date] )
```

If your budget is entered by month, then make sure the DimDate table has a relationship to your budget table and just do the same:

```
Budget = SUM( Budget[Amount] )
Budget YTD = TOTALYTD( [Budget], DimDate[Date] )
```

If your budget is annual, it may be easier to create monthly values in Power Query than writing the DAX formulas. I would create a table in Power Query that had end of month dates and do a [cross join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join) with my budget, then add a column that divided the budget number by 12. Then use the formulas above.